# routing issue from Controller class to JSP page in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

```
        import java.util.Map;            
        import org.slf4j.Logger;
        import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
        import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
        import org.springframework.ui.Model;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
        import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


        @RestController
        public class EmployeeController {

            private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeController.class); 

            @RequestMapping(value="/getEmployees")
            public String getEmployeeInfo() {
                logger.info("inside employee controller");      
               return "getEmployees";
            }

        }
```

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
                pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

```
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Get Employees</title>
        </head>
        <body>this is employee list</body>
        </html>

    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>com.phynart</groupId>
      <artifactId>oAuth-client</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>war</packaging>

      <name>oAuth-client</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

      <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>

      <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

      <dependencies>        
            <!-- <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
             <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency> -->   
             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>    
                <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->        
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
                <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
                <version>4.6.1</version>
                <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.113</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ses -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ses</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.114</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-sns -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sns</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.115</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-admin -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
                <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.7</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.3</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors
                </artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.passay</groupId>
                <artifactId>passay</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hashids</groupId>
                <artifactId>hashids</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.3</version>
            </dependency>   
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
            </dependency>

      </dependencies>
    </project>           


    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
    import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class SpringBootFormHandingApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(SpringBootFormHandingApplication.class, args);
        }   

        @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(SpringBootFormHandingApplication.class);
        }
    }




    spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false
    server.port:8081
    spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
    spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
    security.basic.enabled=false
```

on hitting url "/getEmployees" on port 8081, I dont get the String "this is employee list" as a response instead i get the String "getEmployees"
        returned from Controller class which means the controller is not redirecting to jsp page which should print "this is employee list"....plz cud anyone help me? it is taking much time for me....

[project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VORJc.png)

Comment: change RestController to Controller and Application class add @EnableWebMvc

Comment: thnx a lot @GaneshPatil, it worked, I also tried without EnableWebMvc and using only Controller, it still worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@RestController` : Is combination of `@Controller` and `@RestponseBody`. So everything returned from rest controller method returned as String(`JSON/XML`) as this is what expected from REST Full Web Services.

`@Controller`: It creates the Map of model object and find a view for the return value.

So changing from `@RestController` to `@Controller` should help you.

And Yes need to have `@EnableWebMvc` on Application class.

Comment: thnx a lot it worked, I also tried without EnableWebMvc and using only Controller, it still worked